# Does contract of a Map implementation(or for that matter any collection) require storing reference of the key or value

Tags: java

```
void otherfunc() {
    Map<Key, Value> map = new MyMap<>();
    myfunc(map);
}

void myfunc(Map<Key, Value> map) {
    Key k = someKey;
    Value v = someValue;
    map.put(k, v);
}
```

Does MyMap need to keep those refs to k and v intact from the caller perspective?

Comment: No. You can always retrieve it by using map.get() functions.

Comment: So caller cannot make an assumption that GC would not collect k and v just because of the put and the map still being referenced?

Comment: *Java* requires it. There is no other way it could possibly work.

Comment: @RakeshIyer There is no way for `k` and `v` to lose their values until they go out of scope, as they are strong references to the objects they point to. But once they go out of scope, it's up to the `Map` implementation's discretion what happens with the original objects. See for example [WeakHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

A `HashMap` will store key and value that you `put` in it. You can use `keySet()` to get the set of all keys.

```
team1.put("foo", 1);
team1.put("bar", 2);
```

will store `1` with key `"foo"` and `2` with key `"bar"`. To iterate over all the keys:

```
for ( String key : team1.keySet() ) {
    System.out.println( key );
}
```

will print `"foo"` and `"bar"`.

```
for ( String key : team1.keySet() ) {
    System.out.println( team1.get(key) );
}
```

will print `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about the [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface asserts a K-V mapping that you `put` is generally available to `get` (or found in the list of `values`, etc) at any given future time.  You could, for example, implement an expiring cache with an internal reaper thread that is still a valid `Map`.  (The person who javadoc'd JDK's own [WeakHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) also asserts as much.  Stating such behaviour is 'surprising' but not invalid.)